# AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'tracebacklimit'

Tags: python

```
# Python 3.8    


import sys

print(sys.tracebacklimit)
```

Running the code results with:

```
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'tracebacklimit'
```

But the code below works:

```
sys.tracebacklimit = 3
print(sys.tracebacklimit)

3
```

Question:

**How to get the current `tracebacklimit` value from the code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) (search for `tracebacklimit`) states (with my added emphasis on the first word):

> ***When*** this variable is set to an integer value, it determines the maximum number of levels of traceback information printed when an unhandled exception occurs. The default is 1000. When set to 0 or less, all traceback information is suppressed and only the exception type and value are printed.

In other words, if it's *not* set (or presumably also set to a non-integer), it will use `1000` as a default. So you can get the current value with something like:

```
try:
    tbl = int(sys.tracebacklimit)
except:
    tbl = 1000
```

You could also try the following, it *is* shorter but it doesn't specifically  cover the case where it's set to a non-integer, so it may give you the wrong thing:

```
tbl = getattr(sys, "tracebacklimit", 1000)
```

---

As an aside, you could create a helper function which, given a string representation of the item in question, evaluated it for you:

```
def ensure(str_item, typ, deflt):
    # Execute in "sandbox" context, catching problems.

    local_dict = {}
    try:
        exec(f"myvar = {str_item}", globals(), local_dict)
    except:
        return deflt

    # Extract, and check type of, value.

    item = local_dict["myvar"]
    if typ is not None and type(item) != typ:
        return deflt

    # Was valid, return it.

    return item

# Test code.

import sys
#sys.tracebacklimit = 7         # Uncomment to test if set.
#sys.tracebacklimit = "hello"   # Uncomment to test if set to non-integer.
print(ensure("sys.tracebacklimit", int, 1000))
```

This makes sure the item exists and that it is of the expected type (unless `None` is given for the type).

It's probably not needed for a simple case like this but I always like to add useful helper functions to my ever growing snippet library :-)

Comment: Imagine I have two files: *foo.py* and *bar.py*. I want to check in the *foo.py* if `tracebacklimit` was already changed in the *bar.py*. Yes, I know from the docs that default is 1000. It looks like there is no other way to check - only use `Try/Except` or `getattr`

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko what's wrong with that? This is why it is documented, so you know how to handle it...